# how to set xquery context document in java using saxon 9.2he?

Tags: java, xml, xquery, saxon

how do I execute a simple this xquery, such as this

```
for $elem in /root/element()
return 
    $elem
```

on an xml file using java without using fn:doc?

I keep getting 
XPDY0002: The context item for axis step child::element(xml, xs:anyType) is undefined

--the rundown: I need a simple solution to load an xml file, load an xquery and process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the simplest way I found to do it however I was hoping to use XQStaticContext to "bind" the contextDocument to the expression.

```
XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
XQConnection xqjc = ds.getConnection();
XQPreparedExpression xqje = xqjc.prepareExpression(new FileInputStream("xml\\foo.xquery"));

XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("xml\\foo.xml"));

xqje.bindDocument(XQConstants.CONTEXT_ITEM,streamReader, xqjc.createDocumentType());

XQResultSequence xqjs  = xqje.executeQuery();

xqjs.writeSequence(System.out, null);
```