# How to use Document object in XQuery instead of giving full xml file path to doc() method

Tags: jsp, xquery

I am new to XQuery. I am able to select the data from the XML file with the following query:

```
for $contactscontent in doc('/opt//contact.xml')//Contacts/Contact
return $contactscontent/FirstName
```

Here the problem is that I want to read the data without giving the `contact.xml` path to `doc()` method. I have Document Object in my Jsp as following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new File("/opt//contact.xml"));
```

By using the above "doc" Object I want to read the data from XML file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A Saxon example (though using XQJ) is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112517/271577 . That appears it will let you get rid of `doc(...)` entirely.